# Distributing revenue using crypto

Tags: transactions

I have a few questions and would like to hear opinions from more experienced cryptobros on this idea of mine.

I'm making a game and I'd like to sell it on my website, when a game is bought the money is deposited on a Smart Contract wallet and funds distributed among team members (we are an international team). For clients without crypto, I'd like to setup an on-ramp (?) (MoonPay seems to be the best option), such that the user places an order with their credit card and that in turn purchases tokens for the smart contract wallet.

My questions are:

- Is Polygon the best option for this endeavor? Or is Solana better due to the lower fees?
- Would you recommend keeping Polygon/Solana tokens or setting a fiat off-ramp as well, what about a crypto off-ramp (such as btc or ETH)?
- Do you know of anyone that has done something similar?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.